# How to add multiple children in a list into a pane in Java FX

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create multiple objects and then put those into my scene. For this I am using a loop to create new object in each iteration and insert that into the list.

```
//single object
robot = new Circle(25, Color.BLUE);
robot.relocate(getRandomCoordinates(600), getRandomCoordinates(400));

ArrayList<Circle> particles = new ArrayList<Circle>();

//multiple objects in list particles
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  particles.add(new Circle(10, Color.GREEN));
}
```

Now the main issue is how can I insert the list of objects into my pane. For a single object I am using this:

```
playground.getChildren().addAll(robot);
```

How can I add the list of objects into my Pane - playground ?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but if I interpret it as you have stated it you would just do `playground.getChildren().addAll(particles);`. (For a single node it makes more sense to me just to use `add`: `playground.getChildren().add(robot);`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are only adding a single node, you should prefer the `add(...)` method over the `addAll(...)` method:

```
playground.getChildren().add(robot);
```

`ObservableList<Node>` inherits the [`addAll(Collection<Node>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) method from `List<Node>`. So you can just do

```
playground.getChildren().addAll(particles);
```

Note there is a second method called `addAll(...)` which is a varargs method, taking a list of `Node` parameters. This is specific to `ObservableList` (not just to `List`).

Of course, you can also just add each element one at a time:

```
for (Node node : particles) {
    playground.getChildren().add(node);
}
```

or, if you prefer a Java 8 approach:

```
particles.forEach(playground.getChildren()::add);
```

The difference between this approach and using `addAll(particles)` is that listeners registered with the children list will be notified only once for `addAll(...)`, but will be notified once for each element if you add each element one at a time. So there will potentially be a performance enhancement using `addAll(...)`.